# Animated SearchField doesn't keep its new position

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm animating the location of an `NSSearchField` to move across the window. The animation itself works fine but sometimes the search field does not keep its new location. I've found out that this has something to do with AutoLayout (has been enabled for the XIB) and on iOS there's a function called `layoutIfNeeded` for `UIViews`.

Is there something similar to OS X applications? I've tried this:

```
[self.searchField updateConstraints];
[self.searchField layout];
```

Which seems to work... almost.

During user navigation the search field switches between hidden and visible state. When the user switches between these states everything is fine (the search field stays at its new position).
But when the user sets the focus on the search field (by just clicking on it) and navigates forward and back the search field appears on its old position.

Does anybody have a clue why this may happen?

**Update**

I have just added an observer for the `frame` property of the search field in order to see when the frame changes again. This shows exactly what I've described above: when the user switches between views everything is fine. But if the user puts the focus on the search field and switches the views the `frame` is being set back to its original value.

I also tried to implement the `animationDidEnd:` notification and set the frame explicitly to its new value. But this doesn't work as well.

**Update 2**

This is the code I'm using to animate the search field:

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

```
// Set the properties for the search field animation
NSMutableDictionary *dictSearchFieldAnimation = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
dictSearchFieldAnimation[NSViewAnimationTargetKey] = self.searchField;
dictSearchFieldAnimation[NSViewAnimationStartFrameKey] = [NSValue valueWithRect:self.searchField.frame];

NSRect destinationFrame = self.searchField.frame;
destinationFrame.origin.y = self.searchResultView.frame.size.height + 15;
dictSearchFieldAnimation[NSViewAnimationEndFrameKey] = [NSValue valueWithRect:destinationFrame];
[array addObject:dictSearchFieldAnimation];

// Perform the animation
NSViewAnimation *animation = [[NSViewAnimation alloc] initWithViewAnimations:array];
animation.delegate = self;
[animation setDuration:0.3];
[animation setAnimationCurve:NSAnimationEaseInOut];
[animation setAnimationBlockingMode:NSAnimationBlocking];
[animation startAnimation];
```

Comment: The OS X equivalent of `-[UIView layoutIfNeeded]` is `-[NSView layoutSubtreeIfNeeded]`. You're going to have to show the code for how you set up and execute the animation in order for us to help you. From the symptoms, it sounds like you are animating the frame directly. That is, you're setting the frame (perhaps via the `animator` proxy). You shouldn't do that when using auto layout. You have to adjust constraints, not frames.

Comment: I've updated my question by pasting the code. Yes, I'm adjusting the frame. But how do I adjust the constraints? I know that there is a `constraints` array held by the view. But this is read-only.

Comment: I just checked my XIB and noticed that AutoLayout has been enabled for the views but no constraints have been set, yet. Might this have any impact?

Comment: If you turn on auto layout for a NIB but don't add any constraints, then Xcode will add constraints at build time. However, those constraints will not necessarily do things the way you or your users would want. If you use auto layout, you need to thoughtfully set up constraints just like if you use springs-and-struts, you need to thoughtfully set up autoresizing masks. `NSViewAnimation` is very old-school. Even before auto layout, it was obsoleted by Core Animation. It definitely doesn't play well with auto layout because it sets frames.

Comment: If you use auto layout and add constraints, you can access them using outlets. You can achieve some animations by setting the `constant` property of a constraint through its `animator` proxy. Or you can force the view to lay out using `-layoutSubtreeIfNeeded`, remove constraints, add new ones, adjust the `constant` of others, or whatever, and then force layout again inside an `NSAnimationContext` group with implicit animations turned on.